# How to mask out features outside of the Coverage Layer for Atlas plugin?

Tags: qgis, masking

Using the Atlas plugin for qGIS how do I set the coverage so that it will only highlight the feature(s) I want but still show the surrounding features as grayed out areas?

This would have been easy if I don't need to work with several thousand features.

I am not asking just how to mask neighboring features. I am asking how to to make Atlas dynamically mask neighboring features of the POI.

The idea is similar to this map [here](http://www.hesperus-wild.org/images/MacKay_Lake.jpg).

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Yes, I think a mask is the correct term but I'm looking for a way to automatically applied a mask around the features not selected in the *coverage layer of the Atlas plugin for qGIS*. The link you provided, would require me to mask every feature I want manually - I got several thousands.

Comment: There's a "margin around feature" which if I set it to 0%, I expect Atlas to put the whole feature without margin in the map window. Is this a bug?

Comment: I heard back from the Atlas developer and was told that what I wanted to do is not currently possible.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.oslandia.com/masking-features-in-qgis-24-en.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do some fake styling as mentioned below if you need to apply it to only a couple of layers.

1. Create a copy of your shapefile. This will act as a dummy layer.
2. Add a new field to this shapefile and name it Hightlight.Add it to map. Select the required features and update this field value = 1.
3. Right-click your original layer in map and copy style.
4. Paste the style to your dummy layer. Move this layer above your original layer in table of contents.
5. Right-click dummy layer and set query 'Highlight = 1' so only those features will be visible.
6. Set a 90% transparency to your original layer(you may need to use old symbology in Qgis 1.8).

you would get something like below.

[image]

Comment: I did mention I got several thousand features I need to work on. So, I can't accept this as an answer. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @n1kn0k - how do you determine which features you want highlighted? will you be doing a selection on map? It does not matter really if you have thousands of features..once you have a selection you can update all attributes using field calculator in no time

Comment: most of the features share common borders with each other. Atlas prints the feature in the center, but will also display neighboring features. I'm hoping to find a way to mask the neighboring features being shown on the map.

Comment: let me clarify this a bit. in your example, let's say I have neighboring counties A,B,C,D,E with C in their center. If I use the counties as my coverage, it will print all the features found there but it will also displaying the neighboring features to C. I'm hoping to mask out/apply some transparency to features other than C. I hope I managed to explain myself.

Comment: @n1kn0k - i updated the picture in answer..is this the type of result you want?

Comment: nope. It's a single county per map as POI, the neighbors/surrounding features will be masked. And I hope to use Atlas to generate each feature map. P.S. I'm playing with the "margin around feature" but it just couldn't zoom in enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. The latest discussion I found about this is from September 2013: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Atlas-feature-filtering-td5079184.html

The closest solution is this workaround by Nathan: [How to produce multiple maps with same layout for different layers' extents?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76462/how-to-produce-multiple-maps-with-same-layout-for-different-layers-extents)