# QGIS 2.0 Atlas Generation: Can I force the selected feature to be the last one rendered

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a layer with a number of features that represent zones which share some boundaries with others.  I am using Atlas generator to produce a set of maps, one for each zone extent.  The zones are rendered in different colours and I want the current feature rendered last so it is on top.

That is in the red zone map I want the outline of the red zone (rendered in red ;) drawn last so that *all* the red zone is red and not blue where the blue and red share a boundary.

Alternatively can I suppress the other features altogether?

Comment: Check out the question I just posted on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76462/how-to-produce-multiple-maps-with-same-layout-for-different-layers-extents It might help, but it might not so check it out anyway.

Comment: a clarification about what I mean about 'current' feature.  I mean the feature that being used to define the extent of the current map. 

I iterate over seven features in the layer, 'red', 'blue', 'black',....  For the map with the 'red' feature I want this feature drawn last so that no portion of the red feature (which is coloured red) is overwritten by some other colour.

Answer (score 1):

I find it is worthwhile to create a temporary disposable shapefile to control Atlas. Just copy the layer you have got. Things you could do with this new file (or maybe it's precursor)

- select the features you want and delete the rest
- reorder the features in the file (more on this below)
- be more explicit with the indexing

Shapefiles and GIS programs are a bit stubborn. You can't sort the features with spreadsheet programs (easily) or they will get all jumbled up. The GIS programs tend to read them explicitly in the order the features were created (unless of course it is a case where you expect them to....). Instead of the spreadsheet tightrope use the MMQGIS plugin and the tool MMQGIS|MODIFY|SORT to get your current zone to be the last one.

Hopefully the above is satisfactory. It is not too clear how it is that a zone is the "current" one, but you can ask some more.

ciao

Comment: Hopefully my comment on the main question clarifies what I mean by 'current' in this context.  

In fact I have generated a new layer specially for use with the AG by 'collect'ing the line segments that make up the features in a postgis query.  Normally I have each feature as a separate layer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the shapefile a second time to the canvas, filtering by query?

No need to delete features, accidentally in the wrong file...

Comment: I don't understand how I would do this within Atlas Generator.

Comment: I meant to do this in the project itself. I have not yet used the generator.