# Auto generate map from natural earth data with QGIS or other utility

Tags: qgis, natural-earth

I'm looking at natural earth data to generate each country and save it as a png. What I'm using is: `10m_populated_places`, `10m_admin_0_countries` and `10m_land`.

The populates places is the first layer, then the countries and then the land. For each of the countries I want to:

1) Filter populated places to `FEATURECLA = 'capital'` & `ADM0NAME` = country

2) Filter countries to `ADMIN` = country

3) Set the said country in the middle of the screen and save it as an image. For this I need to zoom in but leave some space around the country.

I'm a complete beginner, what is the easiest way to accomplish this with QGIS or some other GIS software?

Answer (score 3):

The closest to a solution is described by Nathan here: [How to produce multiple maps with same layout for different layers' extents?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76462/how-to-produce-multiple-maps-with-same-layout-for-different-layers-extents)

Easy direct filtering is currently not implemented in Atlas: [How to mask out features outside of the Coverage Layer for Atlas plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53402/how-to-mask-out-features-outside-of-the-coverage-layer-for-atlas-plugin)

Comment: Thank you, this is unfortunate. Do you know of any other software that can accomplish this?

Comment: It's not entirely true that the filtering is impossible. It can be done using a geometry function, eg the expression "within($geometry,$atlasgeometry)" will match all features which fall within the current atlas polygon. So, for your populated places layer you could set it to a rule-based renderer, with the "within" expression matching places within the current country and an else rule hiding the places outside the current country (see http://nathanw.net/2013/12/02/waiting-for-qgis-22-highlighting-current-atlas-feature/). Your #2 condition can be met by setting a filter in the atlas panel.

Comment: Thanks @ndawson! Great to know! I've corrected the answer. Looks like your comment should become an answer though :-)